# Asymptotes of general cubic

Tags: geometry, curves, cubics

I'm trying to understand why the following method seems to work in finding the asymptotes of a general cubic.
Take this cubic equation:
$$x^3+2xy^2-\frac{1}{4}y^3+6x^2-4xy+2y^2+7x-2y+1=0$$
This looks like this:
[cubic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HpkN.png)

Dividing through by $x^3$, gives
$$1+\frac{2y^2}{x^2}-\frac{y^3}{4x^3}+\frac{6}{x}-\frac{4y}{x^2}+\frac{2y^2}{x^3}+\frac{7}{x^2}-\frac{2y}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^3}=0$$

With the understanding that $x$ goes to infinity, we drop terms where the power of $x$ in the denominator is greater than the power of $y$ in the numerator or where the numerator is a constant, and get

$$1+\frac{2y^2}{x^2}-\frac{y^3}{4x^3}=0$$

Here's where I just kind off wave my hands and get the right answer (which is confusing). I identify $\frac{y^3}{x^3}$ with $y$ and $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ with $x$ which gives $$1+2x-\frac{y}{4}=0,$$ which appears to be the asymptote of the cubic.
[cubic with asymptote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueD6F.png)
Insight is appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a coincidence; you're confused because the numbers happen to be close enough that they look like they might work. The method doesn't really make sense: for one thing, you won't always have a $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ or $\frac{y^3}{x^3}$ term, and there's no reason to replace those terms with $x$ and $y$. Instead, consider that $y \approx mx+b$, so what you're really looking for is the solution to $1 + 2m^2 + \frac14m^3 = 0$. This comes out to about $8.06$, very close to the $8$ produced by your hand-waving step. I also get $b \approx 6.29$. Try plotting this and compare with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Theophile. I do now see that $m$ is the appropriate substitution for $\frac{y}{x}$. I do wonder from where you were able to obtain a value for $b$.

Comment: Sure: I took $y=8.06x+b$ and substituted it back into into the original equation. The $x^3$ terms cancel out, and then with the rest, I used your trick of dividing everywhere by the highest power of $x$ (now $2$) and taking the limit. It's easier to see with a simpler example; try, say, $$2x^3+2y^3-9x^2y+20y^2-2=0.$$
If you follow the same steps, you'll see that one of the three asymptotes has slope $m=2$. Substituting $y=2x+b$ and dividing by $x^2$, we get $$15b+80+\ldots=0,$$
whence $b=-\frac{16}3$. (Side note: in my previous comment, the $\frac14m^3$ term should of course be negative.)

Comment: Thank you my man. It is plain to follow as you put it forth. (I did notice that off sign but it did not affect the reasoning whatsoever so I did not mention it.)